# Where is the code for added user registration fields?

Tags: 7, hooks

I've added a few extra fields relevant to my interests to the user registration form. The problem being, I'd like to insert a db_insert function to make use of those fields, but I don't know where the code for the extra fields are. That being said, I'm not entirely sure if altering that code is even necessary.

I'm very new to all this. I'd really appreciate some help, have a good day.

Comment: what is "the code" for you? and what are you trying to do with the db_insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the field settings, tick "display on user registration form".

All of the database stuff is taken care of automatically in drupal so you'll rarely have to worry about that stuff unless you are adding your own custom modules that require tables.

What are you trying to accomplish with these tables? Views etc. will have access to them.

Comment: I'd like to group users together based on their choices in user registration. As several choices can be chosen for each field, and there are three different fields, there are potentially dozens of combinations of field choices. So I'll have to figure out some means of grouping and filtering. It's my first delve into any programming language, so it's slow going. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: For user experience and to make it easier for yourself, I'd consider having each step on a separate page after log in so you can describe the choices if they're complicated

Or if you want it during registration and they're easy choices, you could use taxonomy and  
https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select  if your use case is something like below. ie. Each answer depends on the previous field.

`USA

 - Washington DC

 - New York

 -- Brooklyn


Europe

 - Ireland

 -- Dublin`

Here, Brooklyn and Dublin would be the final choices. If it's not like that, there are other options.